# Not able to find ASP.NET Web Service in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2022, asmx

For creating a simple Web Service in Visual Studio 2022.

- In Visual Studio 2022, Create ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework), and select the Empty template and enter the name and create the project.
- Right-click the soluction, Add ->New Item, then select the Web Service (ASMX).

it will work

Not able to find ASP.NET Web Service  in Visual Studio 2022

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Answer (score 0):

For creating a simple Web Service in Visual Studio 2022.

In Visual Studio 2022, Create an ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework), select the Empty template enter the name, and create the project.

Right-click the solution, Add ->New Item, then select the Web Service (ASMX).

it will work